# NSD Device Lost Message Not Received on Disabling Wifi

Tags: android, android-nsd

I have written a sample app using `NSD` as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html).

The app works fine, it discovers services, resolve services and also report services lost if that service is unregistered.

But in a user scenario like:

1. If `NSD` app is running on a device named `A` and has registered a service on `A`
2. while few other devices named `B`, `C`, `D` are listening to this service.
3. service is discovered by `B`, `C`, `D` - expected behavior
4. now `wifi` is switched off an device `A`.
5. I am expecting to receive a service lost message on devices `B`, `C`, `D`, but I am not getting it?

If I do not switch off `wifi` on `A`, but just close the `NSD` app that unregisters the running service, I receive the service lost message on devices `B`, `C`, `D`.

What could be the reason for this? Is this a known bug with `NSD`? Or this is the way `NSD` behaves?