# NSD Manager keeps old service in memory, even when they are not on the network anymore

Tags: android, nsd

I'm using NSD Manager, and according to the documentation, it keeps a list of service found. But I believe it doesn't update it on every new discovery (as in, it doesn't remove unregistered services)

Is there a way to clear the list or force update the list ? I ask this because I'd like to know when a service is not available and with the current behavior, nsd manager will keep discovering the service 30s-1min after it being unregistered.

Thanks.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34372964/3290339) might give you some insight regarding _Android NSD_ framework and, hopefully, save your time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you recommend a framework/library in particular to use instead ?

Comment: Can&#39;t recommend one. As I said I ended up writing my own library, a simplified one, based on UDP protocol at first and TCP/IP after the discovery happened.

Comment: Any solution found?